# New Unity Input System Movement Isn't Smooth

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to migrate to the new Input System but I've noticed that the movement isn't as smooth as it used to be with the old system.

I have seen some "fixes" that just use Mathf.SmoothDamp or something similar to basically smooth the movement value using it, but i need to make it feel pretty much the same as the old one.

I will either use this or just the old system if there's no other way to fix it.

Example:

Old system

[image: Old system example]

New system

[image: New system example]

PlayerController Input Action:

[image: Input Action image 1]

[image: Input Action image 2]

Old system code:

```
float movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
this.transform.Translate(movement, 0, 0);
```

New system code:

```
float movement = playerController.Default.Move.ReadValue<float>() * speed * Time.deltaTime;
this.transform.Translate(movement, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Could you try `Input.GetAxisRaw`? maybe the new one isn't smoothed by default.

Comment: Is the code placed under `Update()` or `FixedUpdate()`?

Comment: @TomSebty It's in FixedUpdate